# Newtonsoft Get sub key from json without indexer syntax

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I got a json with some nested object, for example:

```
{
  "OrganizationData": {
    "Org1": {
      "Name": "Rega And Dodli",
      "EmployessNum": "100000000"
    },
    "Org2": {
      "Name": "Sami And Soso",
      "EmployessNum": "2"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to get for example the value for the "Name" of "Org1".
I know I can do something like this:

```
var rss = JObject.Parse(mystring);
var value = rss["OrganizationData"]["Org1"]["Name"];
```

My question is if it's possible to replace the multiple indexers part (`["OrganizationData"]["Org1"]["Name"]`) with a single indexer (or something else which is not an indexer) with a single string which is composed of all 3 keys and still get the same value?

For example something like:

```
var rss = JObject.Parse(mystring);
var value = rss["OrganizationData:Org1:Name"];
```

I remember there's something with ":" but this one I tried in the example above did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`JObject.SelectToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectToken_1.htm) method, using period (`.`) as the property path delimiter. For example:

```
var value = rss.SelectToken("OrganizationData.Org1.Name");
```

Comment: I know it's not a part of the original question, but could you also show an example of how to edit and delete a sub key like that?

Comment: I believe it's something along the lines of `rss.SelectToken("OrganizationData.Org1.Name").Remove()`. See the [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) documentation.